# spring url with current local date

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, el

In a spring-mvc app, I need a jsp page to have a url to another page which includes the local current date in the url.  How do I accomplish this?

Here is the code I have so far, which does not work:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" scope="request" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" />
<spring:url value="/calendar?day=${now}" var="calendar_manageUrl"></spring:url>
<a href="${fn:escapeXml(calendar_manageUrl)}" class="btn btn-info" >Calendar</a>
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The url parameter is not in mm.dd.yyyy format.  Instead, it is a long string with the time that breaks the destination jsp.  However, the date is printed correctly in mm.dd.yyyy format in text just in front of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean to store the [`formatDate`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm) result

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" var="formatted" />
```

and then re-use it? Like so

```
<spring:url value="/calendar?day=${formatted}" var="calendar_manageUrl"></spring:url>
```

`<fmt:formatDate>` doesn't do anything to the `Date` object. **A `Date` doesn't have a format.** Printing it gives it a format. Formatting it gives it a format. You need to store and re-use the result of that formatting.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.  +1 Thank you.  That solved the problem.  Have a nice evening.